# ios keyboard is not hiding on resignfirstresponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

Added a `subview` on App delegate window, `textfield` is in `subview`, `startDateTxtFld` will open date picker but date picker remains behind the keyboard. keyboard does not hide on `resignFirstResponder` or `self.view` `eneEditing` setting as `true`.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField == startDateTxtFld )
    {
        startDateSelected =YES;
        endDateSelected = NO;
//        [referenceNmbrTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
     //   [startDateTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];
        //textField.inputView=datePicker;
       // [self.view endEditing:YES];
       // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
//       [APP_DELEGATE.window resignFirstResponder];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
        {
            [startDateTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
            _bottomGap4DatePicker.constant=0;
            datePicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
           // [_subVw4DtPkr becomeFirstResponder];
        }];
       [self.navigationController.view endEditing:YES];
    }
    else if (textField == endDateTxtFld)
    {
        startDateSelected =NO;
        endDateSelected = YES;
       // [self.view endEditing:YES];
//        [referenceNmbrTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
       // [endDateTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];
      //  textField.inputView=datePicker;
      //  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
//        [APP_DELEGATE.window resignFirstResponder];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
         {
            // [endDateTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
             _bottomGap4DatePicker.constant=0;
             datePicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
             //[_subVw4DtPkr becomeFirstResponder];
         }];
        [self.navigationController.view endEditing:YES];
    }
   else
    {
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        _bottomGap4DatePicker.constant=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height +_subVw4DtPkr.frame.size.height;
        _popUpVwConstraint.constant=-30;
    }

}
```

Comment: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];` why using this instead of `[self.view endEditing:YES];` ?

Comment: I have added subview on App Delegate Window,I have used  [self.view endEditing:YES]; it didn't work that's why I use [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];but it is also not working

Comment: Means i am asking that why you have add subview to window? You can add subview to self.view also

Comment: to hide navigation bar,Navigation bar is in App delegate class,so i have to add it on window otherwise navigation bar will be displaying on subview also

Comment: You can directly hide navigation bar. for that you not need to add view on window. you can hide like `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: that will hide the navigation controller from super view on which sub view is added.

Comment: You can hide navigation bar for particular view controller by writing `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` this in `viewwillAppear` and in `viewDidDisappear` write `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;`

Comment: on hiding self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;it is hiding the navigation bar of super view,dts y i hv added it on window

Answer (score 0):

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { {
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing===%@" , textField.text);
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    if (textField==vacDate || textField==vacTime) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        self.view.transform = translation;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        myDatePicker.hidden = NO;
        return NO;
    }
    else
    { 
        if (textField==vacType) {
           translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -60);
        }
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        self.view.transform = translation;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        myDatePicker.hidden = YES;
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working
my view is subview in which 3 text fields are present,I have added subview on App delegate window

Comment: thanks @Kuldeepsingh (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField, worked i had resigned the first responder from third text field in condition 
if(textField == startDateTxtFld || textField == endDateTxtFld){ [rfrncNmbrTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
//and animated picker
}

Answer (score 0):

Hide keyboard Anywhere in IOS :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews){
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder]) {
            [txt resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];    
 }
```

Comment: I have 3 text fields and have to hide keyboard on only1

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solution, like adding

1. `UITextFieldDelegate`
2. `tf_edit.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone`
3. ```
   - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
   {
        return NO;
   }
   ```

Nothing helped.

textFieldShouldReturn was being called. but keyboard was not appearing. I read that it is going to some other textfield when I am clicking DONE button. But there was no other textfield. So instead of applying resignFirstResponder to my textfield name, I applied to the textfield which is a parameter of textFieldShouldReturn function and it worked. I am not sure if it is correct way. It worked for me.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //[tf_edit resignFirstResponder];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```